# I'm getting an error with mysql.connector 1064 (42000)

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, tkinter, mysql-connector

So I'm using MySQL connector and I'm getting an error which is weird because I didn't get any errors with this line before. Please let me know what the issue is.

```
def update(Sno,Passengers,Distance,Cargo,Aircraft):
    myconn=mys.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='adis',database='adis')
    if myconn.is_connected():
        print('Connection successful')
    mycur=myconn.cursor()
    query="update AMAS set Passengers={},Distance={},Cargo={},Aircraft={} where Sno={}".format(Passengers,Distance,Cargo,Aircraft,Sno)
    mycur.execute(query)
    myconn.commit()
    print("AMAS Aircraft Database updated")
```

My error:

```
Connection successful
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vinayak\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\vinayak\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3442, in __call__
    self.__callback(self.__value, *args)
  File "C:\Users\vinayak\Documents\Programs 12th\Project.py", line 146, in exe
    submit()
  File "C:\Users\vinayak\Documents\Programs 12th\Project.py", line 127, in submit
    update(Sno,Passengers,Distance,Cargo,Aircraft)
  File "C:\Users\vinayak\Documents\Programs 12th\Project.py", line 135, in update
    mycur.execute(query)
  File "C:\Users\vinayak\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 551, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "C:\Users\vinayak\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 490, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "C:\Users\vinayak\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 395, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Distance=,Cargo=,Aircraft= where Sno=' at line 1
```

Also, I'm new to Stack Overflow so please mention how I can improve asking questions here withput frustrating others.

Comment: Your parameters are likely to be empty when you call the function.

Comment: Even the parameters are not empty, the SQL may be invalid if any of the columns is of type string.  You should use placeholders instead.